# JavaScript for loop in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am currently stuck with a javaScript for loop.

The situation is like this, in my program there is a function which returns true/ false value in every 200 ms.

The function, which I am currently trying to code, should obtain the value from the above function ( for the ease of reference, I would name it as, function1) and store it in an array. 
I am trying to use a for loop to store those values in an 8 element array.
Shown below is my code,

```
function myFunction1(imagestatus)  // 
{
    var statusArray = ["","","","","","","",""];

    for (var i = 0; i <= statusArray.length - 1; i++)
        {
            statusArray[i] = imagestatus;

        }
}
```

Now, during the first execution of the for loop, it will assign the 0th element of the array, true or false. And during the second execution also it will do the same which is no good.

The task I expect to do is, when the function1 returns its value to myFunction it must store it in the 0th element. Then when it returns again, if its as same as the value in 0th element, store it in the 1st element, if not same, then take a different action.

Comment: I don't see any calls to `function1`, nor do I see any attempts to compare an element of `statusArray` to *anything*.

Comment: Try creating a global variable instead of a local one.

Comment: In this case, it's more idiomatic to write `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` (if you're going to use a for loop).

Comment: I assume your myFunction1() is being called by an outer loop or function that repeats at a 200ms rate., i.e. your timing code is outside of your myFunction1(), so it does nothing more than act as a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an empty array:

```
var array[];
```

then use:

```
array.push(data);
```

To add each datum to the right end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a number of things need to happen.  First, you are asking for a callback function.  Second, you need to move the status array to the global scope.

```
var statusArray = ["","","","","","","",""];
function myFunction1(imagestatus, callback, differentAction)  // 
{

    var i = 0;

    // if its as same as the value in 0th element, 
    while (statusArray[i]==imagestatus)
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (i<statusArray.length && i>0)
    {
        // store it in the 1st element
        statusArray[i]=imagestatus;
        if (typeof(callback)=="function")
        {
           callback();
           return;
        }
    }

    // if not same, then take a different action
    if (typeof(differentAction)=="function")
    {
        differentAction();
        return;
    }
}
```